# Error while connecting Mongo to localhost

Tags: mongodb

I have Robo 3T-1.3 installed on my ubuntu 16.4 LTS.
It is showing me the following error:

`Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:27017.

Error:
Network is unreachable. Reason: couldn't connect to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1:27017) :: caused by :: Connection refused`

How to solve it?

Comment: First check that mongod process is running or not on your system by following command `ps aux | grep mongod`.

Comment: @krishnaPrasad , It is showing me this :  komal     4923  0.0  0.0  14220   976 pts/4    S+   10:36   0:00 grep --color=auto mongod

Comment: So your mongod process is not running that's why Robo 3T-1.3 is not able to connect with mongo on localhost. You can start mongod as `sudo systemctl start mongod` or you check how to start mongod on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly check your mongo status via this command.

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

OR

You can follow this link.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: it is showing this output: mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

Comment: Hey thank you for help..I started mongod and issue got fixed.