# Error on connect to local mongodb with Mongoose when using ts-node?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, ts-node

I'm having issues connecting to my local MongoDB. On connection, it fails with the following error message:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
```

Setup is pretty basic:

```js
const mongooseOptions = {
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  retryWrites: false
}
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/my-app", mongooseOptions).then(() => { // res
  console.log("DB Connected!")
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(`MongoDB connection error`)
  console.log(Error, err)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

I've seen other related posts:

- [MongoDB is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704778/error-while-connecting-mongo-to-localhost): Yes. I can connect to it in the terminal and through the Compass Atlas app. I can also see it in my Activity Monitor
- [IP restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68195088/mongoserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-127107): There are none, it's local. I don't need to update the settings in MongoDB atlas website
- [Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888954/sailsjs-mongodb-connection-error-in-docker-container): I'm not using Docker. Just MongoDB installed through brew. It's been working for years, just started failing since I switched to typescript.

Any help is much appreciated.
Here attached are the mongologs:
[image]

Maybe useful info:

- I tried to connect with a Mongo Atlas URI (so not localhost), and it works.
- I recently updated to Typescript on the server. When I run the code not using `ts-node` but the built version, it works. I'm wondering if it's not something to do with `ts-node`.

Comment: Does the mongod log anything when this code runs?

Comment: @Joe I attached the logs. Not seeing anything obvious.

Comment: That log shows several successful connections from mongoose running on a mac.  What is the problem?

Comment: @Joe MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
reason: TopologyDescription ... (at start of the question)

Comment: Where does that error correlate with the noted log file?